# Android Studio highlights comments written in Cyrillic as typos

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have just downloaded Android Studio for Linux from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com) and noticed that when I write comments in Cyrillic, all the words (except for short ones) are underlined in green, as if they were typos. I don't have this problem in IntelliJ IDEA (which I downloaded from Snap, though).

[image: Android Studio highlights comments written in Cyrillic as typos]

I couldn't find anyone with a problem like this on the net. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the "Grazie" plugin solved the problem.

In IntelliJ IDEA you have the "Natural languages" tab, but there isn't one in Android Studio. The plugin adds that tab, so you can choose any language you want.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to File > Settings > Editor > Spelling, press the <kbd>+</kbd> button and add a Cyrillic Hunspell spellchecking dictionary like [this](https://github.com/grakic/hunspell-sr) one.

###### With spelling mistake:

[image: wsm]

###### Without spelling mistake:

[image: wsm]